# How to display a server's certificate when the cert is signed by an unknown CA?

Tags: ssl, openssl, postgresql, ssl-certificate, tls

I have a server that is giving me TLS problems and I would like to view the cert it is presenting in order to help diagnose the issue. Normally, I would use openssl to display the cert like so:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect facebook.com:443
```

However, I don't know what CA signed this server's cert. I *thought* it was our internal CA but testing suggests otherwise. Thus I cannot use openssl's `-CAfile` or `-CApath` flags to specify the CA.

One more restriction. The server is not an HTTP server (it's postgres), otherwise I would just use `curl --insecure`.

I tried using the `-verify` flag because according to [OpenSSL's documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html):

> The verify depth to use. This specifies the maximum length of the server certificate chain and turns on server certificate verification. Currently the verify operation continues after errors so all the problems with a certificate chain can be seen. As a side effect the connection will never fail due to a server certificate verify failure.

It claims to continue after all errors so all problems can be seen. However, all I get is:

```
1737:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:
```

That is the error message I get with or without `-verify`.

So how can I view the certificate presented by the server?

Comment: So what is it that you want? `s_client` always displays the certificate, even if verification fails. In this case, a successful TLS connection is not established at all. This would suggest the server is malfunctioning entirely or not listening at the port you’re connecting to.

Comment: You are right and I am an idiot >.< I tried again against a server I know to be using a self-signed cert. As you said, SSL successfully displays the cert even though it is not trusted. My other server must be misconfigured somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> How to display a server's certificate when the cert is signed by an unknown CA?

That's easy (and the CA does not factor into things) ... Pipe `s_client` output into `x509` as input with `-text -noout` options. The command below also enlists SNI and TLS 1.0.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect facebook.com:443 -servername facebook.com -tls1 | openssl x509 -text -noout
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            0e:cb:09:39:b2:b1:01:54:b8:95:70:c7:b2:2b:7a:47
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug 28 00:00:00 2014 GMT
            Not After : Dec 30 12:00:00 2016 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = CA, L = Menlo Park, O = "Facebook, Inc.", CN = *.facebook.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:d8:d1:dd:35:bd:e2:59:b6:fb:9b:1f:54:15:8c:
                    db:bf:4e:58:bd:47:be:b8:10:fc:22:e9:d2:9e:98:
                    f8:49:2a:25:fb:94:46:e4:42:99:84:50:1c:5f:01:
                    fd:14:25:31:5c:4e:d9:64:fd:c5:0c:b3:46:d2:a1:
                    bc:70:b4:87:8e
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:51:68:FF:90:AF:02:07:75:3C:CC:D9:65:64:62:A2:12:B8:59:72:3B

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                43:09:93:40:FA:11:4B:30:33:EC:F2:87:6E:8D:71:18:CF:8A:BC:8E
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:*.facebook.com, DNS:*.facebook.net, DNS:*.fb.com, DNS:*.fbcdn.net, DNS:*.fbsbx.com, DNS:*.m.facebook.com, DNS:*.messenger.com, DNS:*.xx.fbcdn.net, DNS:*.xy.fbcdn.net, DNS:*.xz.fbcdn.net, DNS:facebook.com, DNS:fb.com, DNS:messenger.com
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl3.digicert.com/sha2-ha-server-g5.crl

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl4.digicert.com/sha2-ha-server-g5.crl

            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.16.840.1.114412.1.1
                  CPS: https://www.digicert.com/CPS
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.2

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.digicert.com
                CA Issuers - URI:http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            CT Precertificate SCTs: 
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : A4:B9:09:90:B4:18:58:14:87:BB:13:A2:CC:67:70:0A:
                                3C:35:98:04:F9:1B:DF:B8:E3:77:CD:0E:C8:0D:DC:10
                    Timestamp : Dec 16 15:50:03.515 2015 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:44:02:20:28:C8:7D:86:5D:F1:14:32:9D:3A:50:3E:
                                2F:C2:99:80:EC:13:C8:F9:1F:5D:9F:8A:0A:81:FB:F9:
                                EA:02:8C:F5:02:20:28:6F:7F:97:B3:27:01:66:BB:89:
                                4D:C5:A8:53:3A:34:CE:F6:AB:46:AE:F1:70:BD:B8:27:
                                2D:C2:03:28:F6:2C
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 68:F6:98:F8:1F:64:82:BE:3A:8C:EE:B9:28:1D:4C:FC:
                                71:51:5D:67:93:D4:44:D1:0A:67:AC:BB:4F:4F:FB:C4
                    Timestamp : Dec 16 15:50:03.453 2015 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:45:02:21:00:FB:7B:CE:FA:1D:74:6B:EB:76:20:77:
                                16:E3:C0:58:72:B3:21:35:9A:C0:43:2D:A8:90:77:E1:
                                B7:9A:DA:5F:6D:02:20:04:AA:8B:42:D2:AC:CA:D1:87:
                                DF:70:54:C7:1E:22:20:53:36:DF:93:5B:B8:1F:5B:FC:
                                80:05:D1:9A:5A:AB:B0
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 56:14:06:9A:2F:D7:C2:EC:D3:F5:E1:BD:44:B2:3E:C7:
                                46:76:B9:BC:99:11:5C:C0:EF:94:98:55:D6:89:D0:DD
                    Timestamp : Dec 16 15:50:03.663 2015 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:45:02:21:00:FE:2C:B6:D4:EF:95:FF:FC:CD:78:71:
                                81:88:AD:3A:B3:A3:12:0C:82:B2:D8:B5:4C:E6:F1:66:
                                FE:D4:7E:34:A5:02:20:2D:2B:D5:D5:13:84:9C:99:D9:
                                16:65:15:08:DC:59:65:C5:C0:2C:6A:95:E7:E9:83:9F:
                                AF:26:8B:39:10:26:28
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         aa:91:ae:52:01:8c:60:f6:02:b6:94:eb:af:6e:eb:dd:3c:c8:
         e1:6f:17:ab:b8:28:80:ec:dc:54:82:56:24:c1:16:08:e1:c2:
         c8:3e:3c:0f:53:18:40:7f:df:41:36:93:95:5f:b1:d9:35:43:
         5e:94:60:f9:d6:a7:83:6a:7d:c7:b4:f6:0b:90:76:f8:b4:0a:
         c1:31:0d:16:18:b5:cb:71:5c:f9:93:02:21:aa:bb:40:fd:ee:
         0a:1b:a9:f2:c3:0e:25:13:63:67:a2:42:eb:79:ea:5f:8f:fb:
         d8:bb:76:8c:5f:61:ca:2c:be:01:44:09:af:36:1e:a9:f7:40:
         1c:a4:b3:65:78:42:68:04:f0:4b:0c:7f:1f:d9:13:f6:0a:3b:
         35:79:73:69:c7:3c:70:e5:5d:06:98:ea:88:d5:dd:6b:e6:66:
         62:57:cf:af:d0:fb:67:9b:e0:c8:20:3a:b9:b6:4f:39:7a:5f:
         c4:fd:a0:46:8c:bc:c7:44:a7:b3:ab:52:49:db:86:97:ed:2e:
         bc:80:56:95:9f:d2:63:84:57:e7:92:15:32:e4:75:c5:81:52:
         cb:3b:26:e1:5d:4b:fd:e0:39:5e:81:06:af:cc:7e:77:d1:9d:
         9a:06:6f:ef:f7:fc:e2:86:5a:16:5a:c2:04:de:80:e3:78:1f:
         0f:fc:7f:df
```

---

> I don't know what CA signed this server's cert. I thought it was our internal CA but testing suggests otherwise. Thus I cannot use openssl's -CAfile or -CApath flags to specify the CA.

I'm not sure what you are getting at here. I *doubt* your internal CA signed Facebook's certificate. Also, PKIX only allows ***one*** issuer, so there cannot be two or more CA's signatures on the certificate. That's because there's only provisions for one *Issuer*, one *Authority Key Identifier*, etc. Though its not allowed, this use case makes a lot of sense; also see [Certificate with Multiple Signers?](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/pkix/current/msg33236.html) on the PKIX mailing list.

***If*** you want `openssl s_client` to finish with *`Verify return code: 0 (ok)`*, then use `CAfile` with DigiCert's CA. You want the one called [*"DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA"*](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm), and you need to convert it to PEM.

***Fetch DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA***

```
$ wget https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt
--2016-10-13 16:34:12--  https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt
Resolving www.digicert.com (www.digicert.com)... 64.78.193.234
Connecting to www.digicert.com (www.digicert.com)|64.78.193.234|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 969 [application/x-x509-ca-cert]
Saving to: ‘DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt’

DigiCertHighAssuran 100%[===================>]     969  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2016-10-13 16:34:13 (11.6 MB/s) - ‘DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt’ saved [969/969]
$
```

***Convert Certificate to PEM***

```
$ openssl x509 -in DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt -inform DER \
  -out DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem -outform PEM
$
```

***Connect and Verify***

```
$ openssl s_client -connect facebook.com:443 -servername facebook.com \
  -tls1 -CAfile DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem 
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = CA, L = Menlo Park, O = "Facebook, Inc.", CN = *.facebook.com
verify return:1
Server did acknowledge servername extension.
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=CA/L=Menlo Park/O=Facebook, Inc./CN=*.facebook.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
---
...

    Start Time: 1476391066
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
```

---

> However, all I get is:
>
> ```
> 1737:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:
> ```

Just a guess, but... Try using SNI (`-servername` option) and TLS 1.0 or above (`-tls1` option is for TLS 1.0).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I should have clarified that the server I was investigating was not facebook.com (that was simply an illustration). It turned out that the server I was trying to connect to had ssl misconfigured - so what I thought was a verification failure was really a lack of handshake at all. But now I know a lot more about openssl, so thank you!

Comment: @tytk - In the future, please provide accurate information with your question. Also, if you want to use a fake domain, then use `example.com`. IANA reserved it for that purpose.